# color invert on hover over an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I want to invert the color of an image when mouse hovers. But i want only the part of the colors inverted based on image map. I have used image map. The area where my cursor is on image map only those colors should get inverted. 
I have used the following code but it does not work.

```js
function Show(idi){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hiee"; 
document.getElementById(idi).style.z-index = "101"; 
}

function hide(idi){
document.getElementById("mi").innerHTML = idi; 
document.getElementById(idi).style.z-index = "1"; 
}
```

```css
img.invert:hover {


filter: invert(100%);
   -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
   -moz-filter: invert(100%);
   -o-filter: invert(100%);
   -ms-filter: invert(100%);
   
   
  }
 img.invert {
 filter: invert(0);
   -webkit-filter: invert(0);
   -moz-filter: invert(0);
   -o-filter: invert(0);
   -ms-filter: invert(0);
   
  }
```

```html
 <map name="map" id="id_1">
<img   id="12" class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="09"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="08"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="07"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="06"  class="invert"src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="05"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="04"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="03"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="02"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >

   <area    onmouseout="hide('12');" onmouseover="Show('12');" shape="poly" coords="152,222,142,226,135,229,129,227,135,220,125,220,88,215,66,215,52,215,47,212,47,202,50,188,54,170,65,151,76,129,82,115,92,103,100,96,110,90,122,84,123,81,135,92,123,90,144,117,181,158,176,178,174,173,190,172,185,169,162,187,187,170,160,190"
   />

   <area   onmouseout="hide('11');" onmouseover="Show('11');" shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />
     
   <area onmouseout="hide('10');"  onmouseover="Show('10');" id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('09');"  onmouseover="Show('09');" class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('08');"  onmouseover="Show('08');" class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('07');"  onmouseover="Show('07');" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   
 
  <area onmouseout="hide('06');" onmouseover="Show('06');"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  
 
  <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   />  
 
   <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06;" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 
 
  <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06;" class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 
 
   <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06;" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 
 
   <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06;" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('06');"  onmouseover="Show('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area onmouseout="hide('05');"  onmouseover="Show('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area onmouseout="hide('05');" onmouseover="Show('05');" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('05');"  onmouseover="Show('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 
   
    <area onmouseout="hide('05');"  onmouseover="Show('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 
   
    <area onmouseout="hide('05');"  onmouseover="Show('05');" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 
   
    <area onmouseout="hide('05');"  onmouseover="Show('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('04');"  onmouseover="Show('04');" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 
   
    <area onmouseout="hide('04');"  onmouseover="Show('04');" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 
   
    <area onmouseout="hide('04');"  onmouseover="Show('04');" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 
   
   <area onmouseout="hide('02');"  onmouseover="Show('02');"  id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 
   
    <area onmouseout="hide('03');"  onmouseover="Show('03');" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to apply `filters` in `area` tag.

From [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/area.html)

> The area element represents either a hyperlink with some text and a
>   corresponding area on an image map, or a dead area on an image map.
>
> [image]

A workaround to this would divide this into mutiple `img` then set `filter` to `img`

Comment: can i break the image into diffrent png images and place them one above the other and then apply invert color?

Comment: `Filter` can apply to `img` yes

Comment: I have made changes and placed all the images broken into parts as png one above the other. Still filter works on only last image. y is the z index not working?

Comment: I divided the image into multiple image. And trying it with zindex but still not working proper. Only the last image color gets inverted

Comment: broken images http://imgur.com/yMGFR2V , http://imgur.com/fpqmClk, http://imgur.com/R1JhAT9, http://imgur.com/mUKWK5P, http://imgur.com/rpCnGxL

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm asking about divided images, if you can show them in your code, so i can give you a better assistance

Comment: http://imgur.com/FWRCUs4, http://imgur.com/Aw3NhT9, http://imgur.com/IIJqsxf, http://imgur.com/LuUghP9

Comment: oops, sorry. Give me few minutes,to edit the code and put the images.

Comment: instead of this: http://imgur.com/fpqmClk use this: http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png, otherwise it won't show up in the code

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-16285.html i am trying to create something like this link in my end result