# z-index and color invert not working in synch

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, imagemap

I had tried with out breaking the image earlier. Now i have broken the image and tried.I have broken an image down into parts to use for navigation.I have placed these images with z-index on each other.So the image looks like one whole image. I am using image map. I want images to invert color when mouse is hovered over them. So when mouse is on a particular area i change the z-index of that area and bring that area up and then apply color invert css to that image. I have written code for this. But right now it is not working properly. Here is my code.

```js
function myFunction(imgid) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I am inside myFunction function "+imgid; 
    document.getElementById(imgid).style.zIndex = "2";
}



function myClick(iid) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "myClick function "+iid; 
    document.getElementById(iid).style.zIndex = "2";
}

function myOnmouseout(imid) {
document.getElementById("mi").innerHTML = imid + " I am inside myOnmouseout function "; 
    document.getElementById(imid).style.zIndex = "1";
}
```

```css
#container img {position: absolute;}


img.invert:hover {


filter: invert(100%);
   -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
   -moz-filter: invert(100%);
   -o-filter: invert(100%);
   -ms-filter: invert(100%);
   
   
  }
 img.invert {
 filter: invert(0);
   -webkit-filter: invert(0);
   -moz-filter: invert(0);
   -o-filter: invert(0);
   -ms-filter: invert(0);
   
  }
 
  
 <!-- #12:hover {
    z-index: 10; -->
}
```

```html
<body>

 <map name="map" id="id_1">
 <div="container">
 <img   id="02"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
 <img   id="03"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
 <img   id="04"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="05"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="06"  class="invert"src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="07"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="08"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="09"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="12" class="invert" src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >


</div>
   <area    onclick="myClick('12')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('12');" onmouseover="myFunction('12');" shape="poly" coords="173,223,176,222,183,224,185,217,190,199,193,192,198,187,193,176,158,132,126,92,132,93,123,79,101,97,81,123,66,149,57,170,50,194,48,211,136,217,131,225,149,225,149,221,152,221,156,215,158,208,159,197,167,189,170,179,173,177,169,171,190,176,192,187,190,190,182,198"
   />

   <area   onclick="myClick('11')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('11');" onmouseover="myFunction('11');"  shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />
     
   <area onclick="myClick('10')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('10');" onmouseover="myFunction('10');" id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />
   
   <area onclick="myClick('09')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('09');" onmouseover="myFunction('09');" class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />
   
   <area onclick="myClick('08')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('08');" onmouseover="myFunction('08');" class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />
   
   <area  onclick="myClick('07')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('07');" onmouseover="myFunction('07');" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />
   
   <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   
 
  <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  
 
  <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   />  
 
   <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 
 
  <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 
 
   <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 
 
   <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 
   
   <area  onclick="myClick('06')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('06');" onmouseover="myFunction('06');" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area  onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 
   
   <area onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 
   
    <area onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 
   
    <area onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 
   
    <area onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 
   
   <area onclick="myClick('05')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('05');" onmouseover="myFunction('05');" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 
   
    <area onclick="myClick('04')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('04');" onmouseover="myFunction('04');" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 
   
    <area onclick="myClick('04')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('04');" onmouseover="myFunction('04');" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 
   
   <area onclick="myClick('02')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('02');" onmouseover="myFunction('02');"  id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 
   
    <area onclick="myClick('03')" onmouseout=" myOnmouseout('03');" onmouseover="myFunction('03');" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 
<div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
<p id="clicked"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [color invert on hover over an image map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922267/color-invert-on-hover-over-an-image-map)

Comment: How did you generate the coordinates of the <area>s?

Comment: I generated it from the original image, Before breaking it down.

Comment: I am trying to make sumthing like this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-16285.html on my coin image. But the method explained in this link, I dont know how to find relative coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, refactored for jQuery. It works for me. I will try to see what was wrong in your code, but really, you should use jQuery. Probably that css hover thing was interfering with the javascript events.

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('area').mouseover(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("Mouseover for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#mi').text("Mouseout for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',false)
            .css('z-index',1);
    }).click(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#container img {position: absolute;}

img.invert {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}


</style>
<body>

 <map name="map" id="id_1">
 <div="container">
<img   id="02"  src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="03"  src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="04"  src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="05"  src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="06"  src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="07"  src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="08"  src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="09"  src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10"  src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="12"  src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >


</div>
   <area  data-imgid="12"  shape="poly" coords="173,223,176,222,183,224,185,217,190,199,193,192,198,187,193,176,158,132,126,92,132,93,123,79,101,97,81,123,66,149,57,170,50,194,48,211,136,217,131,225,149,225,149,221,152,221,156,215,158,208,159,197,167,189,170,179,173,177,169,171,190,176,192,187,190,190,182,198"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="11"  shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="10"  id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />

   <area  data-imgid="09"  class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="08"  class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="07" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   />  

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 

  <area  data-imgid="06"  class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="06" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 

   <area  data-imgid="05" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="04" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 

    <area  data-imgid="04" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="02" id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="03" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 
<div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
<p id="clicked"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, so the same thing worked with vanilla javascript. The idea being that mouseover, mouseout and click were area events. overlapped images were messing with the :hover style. So I just moved the filters to the invert class and set the image class in the area events.

Comment: Oh thats where it was messing up. Thank you so much. It works perfectly fine now. Is there a way where onclick i can make the inverrted image stay and hover over the other images like before?

Comment: I would use a different class for when the item is "clicked", that would also invert the image. Then you can toggle the class with .toggleClass('pressed') with no other parameters (in jQuery) so it gets on or off.

Comment: Did not understand it.

Comment: I tried that, but once it is pressed it remains inverted color. which is good. But when i click on other image this inverted color should become white again, Insttead it is staying black.

Comment: img.pressed {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}

Comment: .click(function() {
        var imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
        $('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('pressed',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    });

Comment: just toggleClass, without 'true'.